# How to make TabPagerIndicator move while ViewPager is scrolling

Tags: android

Heu guys i am building an app and i have implemented scrollable tabs. i would like to make it google play style like when the viewpager is scrolling i want the tabpagerindicator to move with it. is this possible?? i have tried to use this example but i failed.

[Make TabPagerIndicator Like Google Play](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

My code so far.

```
public class TabsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager
                .setAdapter(new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    }
                });


        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText(R.string.info);
        tab1.setTabListener(this);
        tab2.setText(R.string.graph);
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);

    }

    class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (arg0 == 0) {
                fragment = new InfoFragment();
            }
            if (arg0 == 1) {
                fragment = new GraphFragment();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

Comment: well yes the tabs activity has 2 fragments inside which everyone of them extends FragmentActivity. The tabs activity is only using the viewpager layout so that i can use the fragments to be scrollable

Comment: Oh sorry, I messup with your name class ^^

Comment: can u help me to add this to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confuse by your words: *"the tabs activity has 2 fragments inside which everyone of them extends FragmentActivity"*. They (the Fragments) should extends Fragment and not FragmentActivity..

The right way to have this library is to create (in your case) one `FragmentActivity` (extends FragmentActivity) and two `Fragment`s (extends Fragment). Your FragmentActivity will have an `FragmentPagerAdapter` setting with your `ViewPager` and your `PagerTabStrip` to display the two Fragments.

**All is explain on the GitHub page** in **Usage section**:

Firstly, include the library as local library project:

- Download the zip > Copy/paste the `Library` to your application ([PagerSlidingTabStrip Library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/tree/master/library): you will need `PagerSlidingTabStrip.java` and also the `res` folder as everything in `attrs` file, the `background_tab.xml` drawable, etc. copy/paste it to yours).

Then, your layout with `ViewPager` will be:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myappname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.mypackagename.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        tools:context=".TabsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, your FragmentActivity will be:

```
import com.mypackagename.PagerSlidingTabStrip;

public class TabsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);

        // ActionBar settings
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ViewPager, Tab, Adapter init
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Adapter settings
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    }

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final String[] tab_titles = { "InfoFragment", "GraphFragment" };

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tab_titles[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tab_titles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = new InfoFragment();
            } else {
                fragment = new GraphFragment();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

}

}
```

You **don't need** to `implements ActionBar.TabListener`, to set NavigationMode to `MODE_TABS` and adding Tab dynamically with `actionBar.addTab`.
As you can read on the project page: **compatible with the ViewPager from the Android Support Library**, this is not related with the `ActionBar` but with the `ViewPager`. Your tabs are added in the `Adapter`..

Finally, you can customize your Tabs with xml attributes. These attributes are handled via your `attrs` file and all are visible in **Customization section** on home page:

```
<com.mypackagename.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    myappname:pstsIndicatorColor="#FFFF0000"
    myappname:pstsUnderlineColor="#FFFF0000"
    myappname:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    ... />
```

Hope this helps.